# Exclusão de Muitos para Muitos Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tendo um grande problema com uma exclusão muitos para muitos no Entity Framework 6.
Abaixo segue as minhas três classes.

Classe orçamento.

```
 public class Orcamento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataEvento { get; set; }
        public int QtdPessoas { get; set; }
        public int PorcentagemEntrada { get; set; }
        public int PorcentagemFinal { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorPessoa { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorEntrada { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorFinal { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Obs { get; set; }
        public bool EnviadoPorEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataRegistro { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Servico> ServicoLista { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrcamentoProfissional> OrcamentoProfissionais { get; set; }
        public Orcamento()
        {
            this.ServicoLista = new List<Servico>();
            this.OrcamentoProfissionais = new List<OrcamentoProfissional>();
        }
    }
```

Classe Profissional

```
public class Profissional
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Obs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrcamentoProfissional> OrcamentoProfissionais { get; set; }
    public Profissional()
    {
        this.OrcamentoProfissionais = new List<OrcamentoProfissional>();
    }
}
```

Classe para relacionamento entre as duas classes acima.

```
public class OrcamentoProfissional
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrcamentoId { get; set; }
    public int ProfissionalId { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public virtual Orcamento Orcamento { get; set; }
    public virtual Profissional Profissional { get; set; }

}
```

Quando tento fazer a exclusão de um objeto

```
Orcamento.OrcamentoProfissionais.Remove(objParaRemoção)
```

eu recebo uma exceção:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um pequeno erro conceitual aqui, que se torna um erro significativo na hora de persistir os registros. Quando você faz:

```
Orcamento.OrcamentoProfissionais.Remove(objParaRemoção)
```

Está apagando apenas o objeto da lista `OrcamentoProfissionais`, e não do banco de dados em si. Para apagar do banco de dados, precisa fazer:

```
contexto.OrcamentoProfissionais.Remove(objParaRemocao);
```

Aí sim você terá a remoção em contexto, ou seja, o Entity Framework fará todo o trabalho pesado para você.

No seu caso, o erro ocorre porque você destacou o objeto da lista de orçamentos, mas ele continua existindo no contexto e sendo observado com ele. O que o contexto entende é que você deixou `OrcamentoId` nula (afinal, o objeto foi removido da lista) e tenta salvar o registro com a chave nula. É isso que caracteriza erros com essa mensagem.

A meu ver, o Entity Framework deveria ser mais espertinho e detectar a remoção da forma com que você fez, mas nem todos os cenários conceituais foram implementados no *framework*.

Comment: Obrigado pela ótima explicação! Fiz alguns ajustes no meu código e consegui excluir conforme você falou.
Problema resolvido! \o/